# SAP connector 3.0 .NET set value on table structure

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm trying to get data from SAP via SAP Connector 3.0 on a MVC3 application.

There is no problems with the connection.

My problem is when I try to set values on a structure from a table it says

> "TABLE [STRUCTURE ZHRS_ABSENCES]: cannot set value (array storing element values is null)"

My code is the following:

```
//create function    
IRfcFunction function = conex.Repository
                        .CreateFunction("Z_HR_PORTAL_GET_EMPLOYEE_DATA");

//get table from function
IRfcTable absenceHoli = function.GetTable("P_ABSENCES");

//setting value to structure
absenceHoli.SetValue(0, "0000483"); //this is where the error occurs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the connector you're using, but there's a similar common misunderstanding when using JCo. A table parameter can hold multiple lines. You'll usually have to append a line to the table. This will probably return some kind of structure that you'll be able to fill. [Also check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783739/add-items-to-irfctable)

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need to Append a new row before trying to call SetValue

e.g.

```
absenceHoli.Append();    
absenceHoli.SetValue("ColumnName", "0000483"); // Add further SetValue statements for further columns
```

You can get the column names by putting a breakpoint on after you're got the Table Structure and examining it, which is probably nicer than just specifying column indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to use `Insert`:

```
absenceHoli.Insert();
absenceHoli.SetValue(..., ...);
```